# Construct a regular expression for the set of strings over {a, b} that contain an odd number of a's and at most four b's

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

Construct a regular expression for the set of strings over {a, b} that contain an odd number of a's and at most four b's.

So far, I have $(aa)^*a((b+\varepsilon)(aa)^*)^4$, but I don't think this covers all cases. For example, $abaabaaab$ should fit the criteria, but it wouldn't be in the language described by the above regular expression. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The string abaabaaab has an even number of a’s and so isn’t in the language.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to construct a regular expression for the set of strings over $\{a,b\}$ which contain an even number of $a$'s and at most one $b$.

Strings that contain no $b$ are of the form $a^n$, where $n$ is even. Such strings can be described using the regular expression $(aa)^*$.

Strings that contain a single $b$ are of the form $a^n b a^m$, where $n+m$ is even. Thus either $n,m$ have the same parity. The case where both are even is described using $(aa)^*b(aa)^*$, and the case where both are odd is described using $a(aa)^*ba(aa)^*$.

In total, we obtain the regular expression
$$ (aa)^*(\epsilon + b(aa)^*) + a(aa)^*ba(aa)^*. $$

Answer (score -1):

It says the constraints are

1. Odd number of A's and
2. At most 4 B's
   let's start the expression

->string may start with both A & B

======>(A+B)

->say the first letter of the string be A

======>we need kernels should contain even A's to make it odd

```
   ========>of kind(_a_a_)
            ======>(AA)*;(BAA)*;(ABA)*;(AAB)*
```

->say if the expression has started with B

======>we need to include odd number of A's into the second term

```
 ======>A*B*(say for singular B's)
```

-> and to make whole recursion we will be taking whole (*).

======>((A*B*)+(AA)*+(BAA)*+(ABA)*+(AAB)*)*

So, the final expression that would be accepting
any string that would have odd number of A's and at most 4 B's is :
(A+B).(A+B+AA+BAA+ABA+AAB)*

(not simplified for understanding...)

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. I can match AA with the expression you present as well as BBBBB.

Comment: (I find using capital letters irritating here. The bigger slanted ones can be produced enclosing them (a ($L^AT_EX$) formula) in \$ dollar signs.)

Comment: @greybeard As I already mentioned not simplified further. That's just a regex that fit the given condition and of course it has feasibilties for even more

Comment: To entertain only for almost 4 B's we can rove the whole star